# Dijkstra algorithm implementation in F#

Tags: algorithm, graph, f#

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra algorithm in F# for finding the shortest path in a undirected tree using a heap.

I've used the type PriorityQueue found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Net-Implementation-of-a-d3ac7b9d/sourcecode?fileId=59957&pathId=1866381907) and the code can be found [here](https://github.com/FaguiCurtain/Learning-Fsharp/blob/master/Algo%20Stanford/Algo%20Stanford/Djikstra1.fs).

```
///////////////// preparing the data ////////////////////

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO

open MSDN.FSharp

let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford\PA5 - dijkstraData.txt"
// let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algo Stanford\PA5 - test4.txt"
// val x : string [] =

// original format of each row is "row_number (a1,b1) (a2,b2) ....(an,bn)"

let split (text:string)=
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let split_comma (text:string)=
    text.Split [|','|]


let splitIntoKeyValue (A: 'T[]) =  
    (A.[0], Seq.toList (Seq.tail A))

let parseLine (line:string)=
    line
    |> split
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> not(s=""))
  //  |> Array.map (fun s-> (int s))
    |> splitIntoKeyValue

let y =
  x |> Array.map parseLine

let nodelist = y |> Array.map fst |> Array.map int

let N1 = Array.max nodelist // be careful if there is an image node with a bigger ID !!!


let graphcore = // (int*int) list [] // nodes without outgoing edges will be missing
    (y |> Array.map snd
       |> Array.map (List.map split_comma)
       |> Array.map (List.map (fun (A:'T[]) -> (int A.[0],int A.[1]) )))


let N2 = graphcore |> Array.map (List.map fst) |> Array.map List.max |> Array.max // node max

let N=N2

// non-optimized construction

let graph = 
    let g = Array.create (N+1) []
    for i in 0..((Array.length nodelist)-1) do
        g.[nodelist.[i]] <- graphcore.[i]
    g


let reversegraph = // (int*int) list []
    let (rg:(int*int) list [])= Array.create (N+1) []
    for i in 1..N do
        graph.[i] |> List.iter (fun (node,value) -> rg.[node] <- (i,value)::rg.[node] )
    rg

/////////////////// test ///////////////////

//let PQ1 = new PriorityQueue<int,int>()
//
//PQ1.Enqueue 2 3
//PQ1.Enqueue 3 4
//PQ1.Enqueue 1 5
//PQ1.Enqueue 1 6
//printfn "PriorityQueue %A" PQ1
//
//Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

/////////////////// DJIKSTRA ///////////////////
let limit = 1000000 // max distance limit
let S = 1 // Source
let V = [0..N] |> List.filter (fun s -> not(s=S));;
let A = Array.create (N+1) limit // on ne se sert pas de A.[0]
A.[S] <- 0

let C = Array.create (N+1) -1 // stores the index of the element in X nearest to an element in V.
let D = Array.create (N+1) limit // stores the value of Dijkstra criterion

let inX = Array.create (N+1) false // remembers if the node is in X (= has been processed)
inX.[S]<-true

let PQ = new PriorityQueue<int,int>() // Key = distance to X ; Value = Node 

let init_loop () : unit =
    for node in V do
        PQ.Enqueue limit node 
    for (node,dist_to_S) in graph.[S] do
         PQ.RemoveAt (PQ.IndexOf limit node) |> ignore
         PQ.Enqueue dist_to_S node |> ignore
         C.[node]<-S
         D.[node]<-dist_to_S
init_loop()

let PP () =
    for i in 0..(PQ.Count-1) do (printfn "PQ %i %A" i PQ.[i]);;

 // code to double check everything and DEBUG
let check() : unit=
    let V = [0..N] |> List.filter (fun s-> (inX.[s]=false))
    let mutable temp = limit
    for k in V do 
        temp <- limit
        let check_list = reversegraph.[k] |> List.filter (fun (n,d) -> inX.[n]=true)     
        for (i,d_i) in check_list do
            let y = (A.[i]+d_i)
            if (y  < temp) then temp <- y else ()
        if not(PQ.Contains temp k) then printfn "error at node %d with temp=%d" k temp
                                        printfn "check_list = %A" check_list
                                        failwith "stopping program"
                                   else()


let one_loop() : int =
    // take the first element from the queue
    let z = PQ.Dequeue()
    let W = z.Value
    let l = z.Key
    A.[W]<- l
    // maintain the heap
    // the Key must the Dijkstra criterion
    let update_list = graph.[W]
    update_list |> List.iter ( fun (node,dist) -> if (inX.[node]=true) then ()
                                                     else let x = l+dist                                                    
                                                          if x > D.[node] then ()
                                                              else PQ.RemoveAt (PQ.IndexOf D.[node] node) |> ignore // updater le node
                                                                   PQ.Enqueue x node
                                                                   C.[node]<- W // prédécesseur
                                                                   D.[node]<- x // update la distance à X
                                                                   if node = 196 then printfn "D.[196] = %d" x else ()
                              ) 
    inX.[W] <- true
    // DEBUG check
    check()                          
     // returns W as a result of one_loop
    W

for k in 1..N do // one_loop()
                 printfn "big loop k=%d" k
                 printfn "k= %d W=%d" k (one_loop())

printfn "%A" A
// printfn "%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i,%i" A.[7] A.[37] A.[59] A.[82] A.[99] A.[115] A.[133] A.[165] A.[188] A.[197]
PP()

// stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "%f" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore

// my answer 2599,2610,2947,2052,2367,2399,2029,2442,2610,3068//
// the right answer for A.[188] is 2505...

// solution from Python
let AA =[|1000000;0; 2971; 2644; 3056; 2525; 2818; 2599; 1875; 745; 3205; 1551; 2906; 2394; 1803; 2942; 1837; 3111; 2284; 1044; 2351; 3630; 4028; 2650; 3653; 2249; 2150; 1222; 2090; 3540; 2303; 3455; 3004; 2551; 2656; 998; 2236; 2610; 3548; 1851; 4091; 2732; 2040; 3312; 2142; 3438; 2937; 2979; 2757; 2437; 3152; 2503; 2817; 2420; 3369; 2862; 2609; 2857; 3668; 2947; 2592; 1676; 2573; 2498; 2047; 826; 3393; 2535; 4636; 3650; 743; 1265; 1539; 3007; 4286; 2720; 3220; 2298; 2795; 2806; 982; 2976; 2052; 3997; 2656; 1193; 2461; 1608; 3046; 3261; 2018; 2786; 647; 3542; 3415; 2186; 2398; 4248; 3515; 2367; 2970; 3536; 2478; 1826; 2551; 3368; 2303; 2540; 1169; 3140; 2317; 2535; 1759; 1899; 508; 2399; 3513; 2597; 2176; 1090; 2328; 2818; 1306; 2805; 2057; 2618; 1694; 3285; 1203; 676; 1820; 1445; 2468; 2029; 1257; 1533; 2417; 3599; 2494; 4101; 546; 1889; 2616; 2141; 2359; 648; 2682; 3464; 2873; 3109; 2183; 4159; 1832; 2080; 1831; 2001; 3013; 2143; 1376; 1627; 2403; 4772; 2556; 2124; 1693; 2442; 3814; 2630; 2038; 2776; 1365; 3929; 1990; 2069; 3558; 1432; 2279; 3829; 2435; 3691; 3027; 2345; 3807; 2145; 2703; 2884; 3806; 1151; 2505; 2340; 2596; 4123; 1737; 3136; 1073; 1707; 2417; 3068; 1724; 815; 2060|]

let B = [|for i in 0..200 do yield A.[i]-AA.[i]|];;
let BB = [0..N] |> List.filter (fun s-> not(B.[s]=0))
//val BB : int list = [10; 26; 95; 96; 101; 147; 157; 184; 188; 196]// index of nodes with differences
// Array.partition (fun s->not(s=0)) B
// [for i in BB do yield B.[i]] // donne un résultat similaire...
//
```

I've done already some debugging, inserting a function `check()` (to be deleted when everything is fixed) which will check directly that the heap has always the right value, i.e., that at every moment, the key of any entry in the heap corresponds to the Dijkstra criterion.

For the example graph found here in the same repository (click on the parent directory), dijkstraData.txt, the format is as follows:

On every line, the first element is the ID# n of the node for that line
then we have tuples like (a,d) indicating that there is an edge from node n to node a, and that the distance is d. In this .txt example, edges are two way with same distance, so if you look at it carefully, for example there is an edge from node 1 to node 80 of length 982 and an edge from node 80 to node 1 of length 982.

The solution for distances from node 0 (non-existent) to node I should be summarized in the following array:

> let AA =[|1000000;0; 2971; 2644; 3056; 2525; 2818; 2599; 1875; 745;
>   3205; 1551; 2906; 2394; 1803; 2942; 1837; 3111; 2284; 1044; 2351;
>   3630; 4028; 2650; 3653; 2249; 2150; 1222; 2090; 3540; 2303; 3455;
>   3004; 2551; 2656; 998; 2236; 2610; 3548; 1851; 4091; 2732; 2040; 3312;
>   2142; 3438; 2937; 2979; 2757; 2437; 3152; 2503; 2817; 2420; 3369;
>   2862; 2609; 2857; 3668; 2947; 2592; 1676; 2573; 2498; 2047; 826; 3393;
>   2535; 4636; 3650; 743; 1265; 1539; 3007; 4286; 2720; 3220; 2298; 2795;
>   2806; 982; 2976; 2052; 3997; 2656; 1193; 2461; 1608; 3046; 3261; 2018;
>   2786; 647; 3542; 3415; 2186; 2398; 4248; 3515; 2367; 2970; 3536; 2478;
>   1826; 2551; 3368; 2303; 2540; 1169; 3140; 2317; 2535; 1759; 1899; 508;
>   2399; 3513; 2597; 2176; 1090; 2328; 2818; 1306; 2805; 2057; 2618;
>   1694; 3285; 1203; 676; 1820; 1445; 2468; 2029; 1257; 1533; 2417; 3599;
>   2494; 4101; 546; 1889; 2616; 2141; 2359; 648; 2682; 3464; 2873; 3109;
>   2183; 4159; 1832; 2080; 1831; 2001; 3013; 2143; 1376; 1627; 2403;
>   4772; 2556; 2124; 1693; 2442; 3814; 2630; 2038; 2776; 1365; 3929;
>   1990; 2069; 3558; 1432; 2279; 3829; 2435; 3691; 3027; 2345; 3807;
>   2145; 2703; 2884; 3806; 1151; 2505; 2340; 2596; 4123; 1737; 3136;
>   1073; 1707; 2417; 3068; 1724; 815; 2060|]

I got the results from another code in Python the solution differs at nodes 
[10; 26; 95; 96; 101; 147; 157; 184; 188; 196] only.

I can't figure out if my algo is wrong as I got a 95% good answer. Maybe I've missed some cases, or I have a bug in the I/O part and don't play with the same graph.

the data file:

> 1 80,982  163,8164    170,2620    145,648 200,8021    173,2069    92,647  26,4122 140,546 11,1913 160,6461    27,7905 40,9047 150,2183    61,9146 159,7420    198,1724    114,508 104,6647    30,4612 99,2367 138,7896    169,8700    49,2437 125,2909    117,2597    55,6399 
>   2 42,1689 127,9365    5,8026  170,9342    131,7005    172,1438    34,315  30,2455 26,2328 6,8847  11,1873 17,5409 157,8643    159,1397    142,7731    182,7908    93,8177 
>   3 57,1239 101,3381    43,7313 41,7212 91,2483 31,3031 167,3877    106,6521    76,7729 122,9640    144,285 44,2165 6,9006  177,7097    119,7711
>   4 162,3924    70,5285 195,2490    72,6508 126,2625    121,7639    31,399  118,3626    90,9446 127,6808    135,7582    159,6133    106,4769    52,9267 190,7536    78,8058 75,7044 116,6771    49,619  107,4383    89,6363 54,313
>   5 200,4009    112,1522    25,3496 23,9432 64,7836 56,8262 120,1862    2,8026  90,8919 142,1195    81,2469 182,8806    17,2514 83,8407 146,5308    147,1087    51,22
>   6 141,8200    98,5594 66,6627 159,9500    143,3110    129,8525    118,8547    88,2039 83,4949 165,6473    162,6897    184,8021    123,13  176,3512    195,2233    42,7265 47,274  132,1514    2,8847  171,3722    3,9006
>   7 156,7027    187,9522    87,4976 121,8739    56,6616 10,2904 71,8206 53,179  146,4823    165,6019    125,5670    27,4888 63,9920 150,9031    84,4061 
>   8 152,1257    189,2780    58,4708 26,8342 199,1918    31,3987 35,3160 71,5829 27,3483 69,8815 130,55  168,2076    122,5338    73,4528 28,9996 17,3535 40,3193 72,7308 24,8434 87,2833 25,3949 175,1022    177,8508
>   9 152,1087    115,7827    17,7002 72,794  150,4539    190,3613    95,9480 36,5284 166,8702    63,1753 199,70  131,700 76,9340 70,2    139,8701    140,4163    180,5995
>   10    57,9988 78,3771 62,4816 137,5273    7,2904  187,4786    184,3207    96,807  31,1184 88,2539 135,4650    168,9495    164,3866    11,8988 116,1493    51,5578 171,2029
>   11    1,1913  185,2045    77,815  22,8425 181,8448    47,8727 81,7299 150,4802    178,1696    28,2275 183,594 131,833 157,8497    25,5057 59,3203 10,8988 2,1873  134,294 83,4211 124,6180
>   12    78,5753 17,4602 62,5676 16,8068 60,5933 67,371  71,6734 53,7001 72,3626 34,6690 59,761  18,1520 128,7542    38,6699 57,9416 
>   13    144,9987    59,9801 97,7026 50,758  43,5400 163,3870    178,4194    151,9629    45,1794 105,6821    29,2784 172,2070    57,6850 77,8638 135,861 
>   14    149,4352    187,4874    26,3841 128,9662    155,4446    118,373 123,2733    106,7912    169,4333    53,9197 161,4275    126,9602    73,4106 160,7860    131,358 141,4477    119,960 43,3199 47,7898 175,6718    177,6741    60,2464 127,5682    31,1945 143,5848    94,3551 82,3283 
>   15    42,1789 22,3571 25,7019 163,818 56,2334 100,809 143,1041    107,4589    190,6854    169,7485    94,9606 34,7961 54,8983 157,2136    24,8040 
>   16    200,2848    198,2223    92,2896 18,8663 27,8673 75,4116 150,1680    36,1555 41,2747 90,4558 68,5894 12,8068 42,2596 185,6280    171,3482    109,1469    127,9807    178,1714    35,839  56,9828 134,5203    55,6680 110,4252
>   17    26,1275 45,5114 142,8016    83,4615 140,6440    8,3535  69,3610 153,8545    9,7002  12,4602 173,7312    114,8915    108,1942    54,3115 66,6176 190,7000    70,3899 5,2514  178,7464    166,4762    2,5409  146,5362    117,6266
>   18    57,4216 80,5252 86,7517 62,1926 120,44  173,7256    133,2702    148,589 167,7625    16,8663 170,4989    118,6388    142,332 95,6122 99,5717 154,453 150,5150    149,2664    146,9000    171,4403    111,785 12,1520 
>   19    33,6938 77,7013 187,107 109,8397    88,2002 95,8691 132,3157    195,5038    154,4320    23,8560 152,9751    185,5896    119,7406    160,3997    80,62
>   20    66,2667 173,2676    43,8105 135,6434    33,6387 74,6183 106,8785    75,2484 130,9048    56,7194 50,9507 88,3014 124,392 61,2580 90,7372 92,1704 87,2639 154,2398    41,4203 85,1435 169,5990    166,6086    28,2234 145,8099
>   21    23,5183 40,2199 31,2556 71,4986 165,2151    193,494 154,1845    111,3060    85,2880 101,2775    182,2447    80,9884 87,2681 102,6643    131,3748
>   22    92,5592 64,4257 11,8425 24,594  15,3571 42,3783 41,1374 114,9960    144,9362    146,3620    71,3243 143,8603    131,6075    192,4606    108,9656    168,4356    177,8713    132,1560
>   23    143,7543    161,6863    45,8074 165,208 21,5183 118,5079    40,8336 27,9054 112,3201    135,4560    167,2133    188,4236    166,8077    195,3179    48,4485 137,7591    99,6485 5,9432  71,3316 96,2431 125,922 19,8560 
>   24    141,6862    197,9337    66,5879 59,6941 70,4670 55,4106 103,8083    61,7906 48,7959 151,784 177,393 102,8731    199,2838    73,3509 8,8434  187,9327    22,594  150,5669    164,7312    157,9540    15,8040 
>   25    115,9233    197,3875    185,3573    72,2332 104,4899    137,5378    8,3949  5,3496  77,2729 136,9251    143,108 83,9569 15,7019 48,3214 155,3242    153,2477    129,3005    132,219 11,5057 37,1591 68,4188 
>   26    14,3841 8,8342  1,4122  147,5759    113,5553    157,7   65,9434 116,4221    66,2747 138,7027    145,6697    130,5706    60,701  127,9896    136,7200    17,1275 120,5788    175,6165    70,9252 95,36   106,6940    2,2328  96,425  51,9329 183,4842    196,6754
>   27    23,9054 78,3066 8,3483  1,7905  152,2124    108,9929    63,3896 151,5915    111,3101    34,8912 182,6234    133,7749    16,8673 192,5344    114,714 168,1578    175,210 138,5918    7,4888  122,84
>   28    8,9996  188,3816    116,2638    132,5604    20,2234 178,3642    76,3705 122,9165    184,4164    198,366 161,9217    160,9059    56,5375 120,8874    11,2275 111,4495    193,9441    157,6880    48,2803 
>   29    78,8190 144,6452    114,9478    156,5083    62,9692 121,4537    184,9797    109,6873    153,5446    67,3449 172,5830    111,1005    100,1642    148,3252    13,2784 
>   30    78,5469 119,7372    144,1616    130,1356    59,4458 40,9818 79,503  43,6233 148,4760    42,263  1,4612  57,5668 185,3846    101,6979    94,6976 106,7819    2,2455  71,9294 
>   31    4,399   8,3987  50,2598 75,7688 47,7840 99,8583 190,5055    112,5231    114,7617    118,6949    180,3598    21,2556 199,5564    14,1945 3,3031  35,9855 10,1184 146,2837    51,3739 83,6588 46,5964 
>   32    136,3823    77,1689 92,3395 121,1615    85,7494 173,9631    177,6902    88,8129 36,7329 116,6065    61,3332 68,7352 119,1914    82,8571 70,9909 
>   33    144,4841    173,5949    170,3648    113,652 110,1986    82,3577 61,1837 97,5671 55,1252 19,6938 48,914  74,3642 125,67  89,3089 176,3258    20,6387 138,6960    153,6574    171,3913
>   34    86,6435 156,8641    72,2540 181,5267    27,8912 58,8824 179,8528    62,9864 70,2348 57,5471 53,236  168,3923    101,3383    142,7791    55,7174 2,315   147,9758    15,7961 199,8196    12,6690 
>   35    57,3693 8,3160  144,3087    114,490 65,8910 178,5774    172,992 16,839  118,8640    41,6749 31,9855 39,853  64,6071 166,2816    184,7437    49,3098 182,7369    110,4985    93,8775 
>   36    80,2032 130,7589    123,6226    16,1555 150,116 88,7759 100,8612    9,5284  198,6280    49,953  143,5111    42,4917 134,979 159,6043    32,7329 67,2380 148,9550    48,7266 
>   37    197,9188    119,9313    187,4105    191,3573    109,2135    75,751  200,7541    139,8208    155,609 142,6433    25,1591 132,821 156,7714    107,1144    99,7757 
>   38    91,7087 88,502  132,6092    126,5441    147,8391    12,6699 130,5227    146,4400    108,8712    100,1369    134,4730    87,2975 99,6169 183,5213    109,4945
>   39    200,4319    98,3993 130,2414    40,2489 196,9267    133,8145    82,3528 44,9175 42,5464 127,6103    93,6132 180,9506    192,7454    119,1376    115,983 81,7400 35,853
>   40    23,8336 1,9047  120,7760    101,2885    21,2199 144,7772    96,5739 136,4658    184,4306    189,4263    30,9818 39,2489 108,8883    8,3193  80,9657 181,2338    162,3056    71,2826 68,5800 
>   41    200,2622    78,63   66,4654 198,7215    59,284  75,7333 22,1374 181,5235    16,2747 154,901 150,7278    3,7212  103,7917    163,5256    20,4203 91,7776 35,6749 147,1858    165,3741    107,8116
>   42    160,2382    156,6539    6,7265  15,1789 61,8096 164,347 194,6498    172,5383    104,2726    124,3496    161,4792    159,5951    117,7074    2,1689  186,9391    62,3249 79,9404 39,5464 187,3075    22,3783 30,263  16,2596 137,4572    163,1278    60,6663 70,9396 36,4917 73,9154 
>   43    200,8943    159,9621    97,3906 20,8105 164,6849    13,5400 3,7313  133,8488    108,8964    30,6233 79,5052 131,8231    167,8120    14,3199 130,2685    138,7965    177,9544    143,1171    65,5805 118,8008    140,4482    93,8479 
>   44    197,4900    144,2276    198,2619    39,9175 87,7875 191,8130    166,6953    170,6940    163,18  79,9988 145,2888    173,5518    57,9979 82,3134 54,4113 3,2165
>   45    57,4630 23,8074 112,9496    130,4994    86,8207 17,5114 120,5279    169,662 162,3436    170,8060    118,5918    124,3290    110,8317    13,1794 167,1163
>   46    57,2413 152,9550    86,7512 123,132 138,2860    195,8206    176,9923    119,2687    54,9328 196,9632    73,5109 31,5964 173,2969    193,199 80,7968 194,2429
>   47    57,9584 114,9480    145,9483    190,5892    182,8382    31,7840 129,9533    142,5297    58,1229 146,2959    6,274   14,7898 189,5939    11,8727 76,2138 70,2236 
>   48    152,5835    23,4485 33,914  24,7959 25,3214 135,8869    53,3578 162,201 28,2803 141,7941    36,7266 85,2792 86,3588 124,2593    130,7921
>   49    160,8648    154,2962    109,7520    36,953  178,9747    192,3113    112,2935    35,3098 71,3441 4,619   96,9901 171,9736    163,4688    1,2437  133,5167    117,2896    105,9278
>   50    152,5767    112,6454    185,3968    77,5220 20,9507 165,2667    98,990  187,2485    198,3798    13,758  128,2987    189,7031    52,9931 127,3622    31,2598 179,2502    191,5026    153,4905
>   51    80,7589 72,4882 137,1096    138,8755    109,662 67,4225 181,158 132,6107    189,8899    159,3017    5,22    10,5578 31,3739 120,5675    26,9329 176,1625
>   52    4,9267  115,4973    159,7816    185,8925    188,7805    97,9063 50,9931 137,9846    91,424  150,634 56,2416 107,3647    68,7601 168,1134    179,3504
>   53    14,9197 114,7352    156,4662    62,153  85,1227 177,9852    34,236  7,179   12,7001 48,3578 71,9285 86,7353 150,662 183,5304    125,8054    54,8361 
>   54    197,2223    66,2906 136,1794    188,4883    17,3115 109,7832    44,4113 182,438 15,8983 200,4899    112,2279    169,2296    4,313   53,8361 138,6261    46,9328 
>   55    33,1252 188,5181    101,6050    24,4106 169,7795    149,3088    34,7174 193,8583    1,6399  145,3342    105,8477    166,3686    121,44  16,6680 82,3547 
>   56    101,3516    20,7194 179,5284    127,3031    5,8262  161,9811    16,9828 15,2334 52,2416 7,6616  77,7923 182,7267    88,3375 61,1315 117,1934    28,5375 124,552 100,361 
>   57    18,4216 94,558  186,8815    3,1239  85,6678 45,4630 46,2413 35,3693 84,6563 185,9772    67,8012 47,9584 155,893 64,810  10,9988 80,8722 160,2058    59,2689 79,2330 30,5668 184,7592    44,9979 162,6483    116,656 34,5471 106,4868    131,6342    183,9093    13,6850 12,9416 
>   58    152,5877    98,3677 8,4708  130,7020    59,5735 121,8818    47,1229 102,6906    150,4857    90,7141 86,5989 175,3675    79,2365 34,8824 186,8993    125,1050    74,7934 147,2267    193,6166
>   59    86,1293 147,2651    149,2405    141,9126    112,4585    58,5735 74,4470 24,6941 199,8958    57,2689 13,9801 162,391 30,4458 180,2435    41,284  72,7154 101,1804    87,4628 168,4170    99,671  70,8055 11,3203 12,761
>   60    200,3269    98,2073 26,701  185,6670    120,2231    14,2464 127,1402    12,5933 42,6663 189,4415    107,52  146,2317    112,2570    154,6667    177,5345    172,2781
>   61    1,9146  159,49  33,1837 42,8096 20,2580 24,7906 87,9053 163,448 190,9775    155,5301    173,4803    115,3324    196,5577    171,6888    32,3332 56,1315 131,6924    195,8928
>   62    97,9163 53,153  120,3851    18,1926 154,3238    12,5676 88,9007 152,7404    29,9692 161,4144    10,4816 105,2736    42,3249 107,5324    115,1913    121,4145    116,7419    34,9864 193,6610    103,8383
>   63    141,5607    77,5873 27,3896 169,5160    95,5264 69,2323 125,1315    158,5709    102,5806    9,1753  103,9314    71,3007 131,5257    92,9006 96,5638 7,9920
>   64    57,810  98,3909 97,2201 22,4257 120,2385    177,7660    83,2716 81,9744 111,2663    145,2685    130,2493    148,6419    106,256 141,158 86,414  87,9403 121,771 102,4635    5,7836  67,2090 35,6071 131,4631    182,4701    110,6711
>   65    152,3595    66,6930 26,9434 97,6170 123,9599    175,7920    155,5533    102,1652    77,4069 198,3575    81,3054 199,11  95,6605 35,8910 43,5805 71,439  134,9956    74,6617 165,3705    140,5376
>   66    80,2902 68,8312 142,777 156,2965    41,4654 6,6627  84,7710 102,3328    65,6930 54,2906 24,5879 112,2271    93,5873 94,3424 20,2667 26,2747 130,5826    17,6176 69,824  89,3012 
>   67    57,8012 102,5417    175,5048    153,6204    12,371  137,1414    133,3802    64,2090 98,980  200,475 171,1394    36,2380 29,3449 124,1880    51,4225 195,5737    100,6216    103,1468
>   68    141,3540    197,8223    78,7924 66,8312 144,2277    174,7082    16,5894 163,4920    146,3895    52,7601 140,9624    40,5800 25,4188 32,7352 186,2528
>   69    8,8815  198,6284    17,3610 156,9959    75,3354 168,2357    102,1172    190,8022    139,9030    161,6171    96,4815 189,5215    66,824  94,1427 63,2323 
>   70    4,5285  24,4670 148,7231    26,9252 17,3899 59,8055 47,2236 42,9396 175,3256    149,2366    92,96   153,6532    178,3394    168,1295    156,4830    34,2348 9,2 124,9089    32,9909 183,5332
>   71    8,5829  22,3243 138,1229    81,1711 170,1539    49,3441 23,3316 134,7485    12,6734 30,9294 21,4986 142,6038    65,439  7,8206  40,2826 145,6127    53,9285 63,3007 186,7143    171,6702
>   72    4,6508  78,5839 119,6215    114,8350    9,794   8,7308  113,8782    102,3377    34,2540 25,2332 59,7154 172,3153    89,4836 178,5128    51,4882 120,2287    174,2019    153,541 96,859  146,4264    171,8573    157,604 12,3626 
>   73    14,4106 8,4528  159,4969    97,6534 77,2438 24,3509 174,2581    150,8061    139,4428    149,5233    42,9154 90,5133 78,212  194,8521    172,2239    46,5109 
>   74    159,8960    33,3642 59,4470 20,6183 99,7031 179,1223    93,5576 164,8627    58,7934 65,6617 110,6731    108,8251    165,2602    121,1468    182,1873    176,8129
>   75    115,9140    141,9237    80,2187 86,259  20,2484 92,6095 97,1883 41,7333 87,3244 69,3354 120,6892    131,5902    31,7688 108,5943    4,7044  16,4116 191,1403    81,2609 37,751
>   76    115,7291    185,3674    181,3275    47,2138 143,1079    28,3705 125,1865    178,8433    3,7729  114,9690    100,1793    200,4623    199,6878    138,5683    141,1969    126,9595    9,9340  83,4424 89,6942 
>   77    112,3500    160,105 189,5702    191,5135    124,8896    198,5081    19,7013 73,2438 63,5873 129,2337    11,815  133,2481    192,561 32,1689 50,5220 87,7040 25,2729 65,4069 106,9161    153,4483    56,7923 172,4771    13,8638 
>   78    10,3771 68,7924 12,5753 30,5469 158,6367    122,6207    27,3066 116,2732    41,63   72,5839 161,6310    4,8058  104,1377    83,3955 29,8190 98,6603 154,8423    137,1910    135,6919    73,212  145,7244
>   79    141,7918    101,3205    165,3768    96,3059 119,4117    152,6519    57,2330 42,9404 166,8726    161,8395    30,503  89,5169 134,5792    117,9043    129,7314    43,5052 109,9677    58,2365 44,9988 167,820 193,7737    194,5784
>   80    36,2032 84,4645 1,982   115,1417    151,6728    112,5208    51,7589 152,9606    113,917 18,5252 121,2257    75,2187 57,8722 133,7217    179,7729    119,108 66,2902 40,9657 97,7213 172,7715    89,7224 19,62   46,7968 21,9884 
>   81    115,2608    197,5540    97,8866 101,4493    64,9744 11,7299 71,1711 109,2519    136,1409    39,7400 75,2609 142,424 141,4032    183,3061    184,4485    95,7627 5,2469  143,9810    65,3054 89,6124 
>   82    33,3577 130,3349    156,4691    39,3528 173,591 177,7882    44,3134 116,8491    132,4162    135,519 131,3457    128,6834    32,8571 55,3547 14,3283 
>   83    78,3955 6,4949  185,9306    17,4615 64,2716 25,9569 149,6823    5,8407  167,8200    117,8516    165,1555    151,162 31,6588 76,4424 11,4211 
>   84    57,6563 80,4645 119,6417    66,7710 198,5999    136,4270    86,195  104,5330    154,5421    137,4367    95,3812 159,8763    170,2436    107,2954    85,9888 134,9312    7,4061
>   85    57,6678 160,3613    156,6669    168,6193    136,6221    180,5525    32,7494 118,1102    192,544 129,517 93,2349 87,7478 189,1147    53,1227 20,1435 167,8110    133,836 84,9888 132,3873    128,4644    110,6060    21,2880 48,2792 
>   86    115,4291    197,9714    144,8808    59,1293 126,937 189,1115    18,7517 45,8207 46,7512 177,7010    180,4604    75,259  157,4447    84,195  34,6435 120,5230    64,414  184,801 58,5989 142,1663    53,7353 117,4220    48,3588 
>   87    160,8712    119,518 75,3244 94,9647 59,4628 61,9053 44,7875 168,9716    64,9403 164,3629    20,2639 8,2833  77,7040 7,4976  159,19  85,7478 191,6921    88,8011 167,1022    158,4081    110,1219    21,2681 38,2975 
>   88    6,2039  62,9007 20,3014 113,7322    136,9026    32,8129 38,502  151,2295    150,6770    183,5547    36,7759 87,8011 94,4629 115,6611    19,2002 161,1726    56,3375 10,2539 125,5012    89,6267 
>   89    33,3089 72,4836 123,1723    79,5169 174,858 76,6942 4,6363  199,2446    105,2736    66,3012 180,6612    80,7224 163,4055    88,6267 81,6124 
>   90    152,4427    4,9446  115,1117    119,928 185,7284    20,7372 16,4558 108,9076    179,3149    139,7846    58,7141 5,8919  73,5133 144,6223    174,6914
>   91    160,383 181,5060    174,3418    113,4626    95,1806 3,2483  192,6625    52,424  115,1105    137,4129    142,9164    41,7776 158,5553    38,7087 200,1988
>   92    1,647   130,4320    108,1844    134,610 194,426 177,3182    75,6095 20,1704 94,6085 128,556 22,5592 16,2896 186,7980    32,3395 139,6763    121,3819    138,8080    70,96   63,9006 
>   93    66,5873 39,6132 181,4071    154,4073    85,2349 106,7477    74,5576 150,9213    98,6617 147,7807    43,8479 152,6543    35,8775 167,5670    2,8177
>   94    57,558  66,3424 92,6085 120,2733    87,9647 30,6976 191,8318    139,7116    109,1299    88,4629 170,9318    69,1427 14,3551 115,3350    171,9959    15,9606 
>   95    119,8126    112,555 120,1104    18,6122 91,1806 173,4092    196,231 26,36   147,1278    19,8691 125,2917    9,9480  63,5264 81,7627 84,3812 65,6605 105,6026
>   96    40,5739 79,3059 104,9639    113,712 162,3737    155,1251    10,807  49,9901 151,5643    23,2431 72,859  26,425  69,4815 143,9274    183,5939    63,5638 147,6736    193,8831
>   97    33,5671 185,7065    52,9063 64,2201 188,4695    192,6411    43,3906 73,6534 13,7026 112,7969    81,8866 80,7213 62,9163 65,6170 140,6527    75,1883 137,4667
>   98    115,5825    131,4614    64,3909 155,5515    139,1235    39,3993 102,8330    60,2073 200,2690    166,2364    78,6603 162,6139    58,3677 117,9545    6,5594  144,7198    50,990  150,2093    143,4300    67,980  93,6617 
>   99    104,9140    18,5717 174,5675    157,6818    132,6234    182,2897    151,4990    183,3577    59,671  133,2090    23,6485 153,4560    31,8583 74,7031 1,2367  127,1408    37,7757 193,4566    194,5832    38,6169 
>   100   159,6567    137,7178    163,9709    190,6674    36,8612 142,2994    76,1793 67,6216 29,1642 56,361  144,6605    128,2584    153,9522    145,5512    15,809  38,1369 
>   101   188,8531    40,2885 157,1393    171,4083    55,6050 144,3619    3,3381  113,5024    81,4493 163,6033    56,3516 129,8821    184,9591    59,1804 79,3205 30,6979 138,2902    143,4042    34,3383 21,2775 
>   102   98,8330 66,3328 144,7884    72,3377 24,8731 181,3585    137,6814    172,6572    58,6906 64,4635 117,2689    177,4462    67,5417 183,9634    69,1172 65,1652 178,1334    161,8230    63,5806 140,6370    21,6643 
>   103   200,6851    123,8756    24,8083 41,7917 191,9683    63,9314 112,7409    110,491 131,2920    196,696 186,9654    62,8383 113,5248    67,1468 114,1318
>   104   141,8162    78,1377 42,2726 123,9213    1,6647  126,8615    200,7083    197,4174    84,5330 192,4219    142,6236    99,9140 96,9639 25,4899 172,561 179,8827    169,3712
>   105   185,1033    62,2736 113,3388    116,7899    89,2736 164,4661    183,7722    55,8477 190,2518    180,341 95,6026 119,9930    120,9333    13,6821 49,9278 
>   106   14,7912 4,4769  115,9598    141,674 112,4854    20,8785 64,256  181,5332    190,3305    3,6521  30,7819 93,7477 26,6940 77,9161 57,4868 111,6460
>   107   114,2032    123,4581    62,5324 187,2610    60,52   116,9864    84,2954 182,8313    37,1144 169,668 52,3647 4,4383  41,8116 146,7862    112,7448    15,4589 176,6806
>   108   200,9976    185,8699    17,1942 40,8883 156,7039    92,1844 75,5943 22,9656 43,8964 27,9929 174,5669    90,9076 145,521 143,972 113,4342    74,8251 126,525 38,8712 
>   109   152,2743    136,8658    81,2519 169,382 51,662  49,7520 129,2464    79,9677 54,7832 37,2135 94,1299 185,6644    29,6873 19,8397 16,1469 38,4945 
>   110   197,751 33,1986 145,6099    118,9403    74,6731 126,1073    103,491 35,4985 137,8848    165,4097    85,6060 87,1219 45,8317 64,6711 16,4252 
>   111   197,4083    144,5456    114,2027    64,2663 27,3101 191,5723    162,8771    152,1940    28,4495 106,6460    29,1005 130,9137    133,6767    18,785  160,9702    21,3060 
>   112   23,3201 141,130 80,5208 181,2524    95,555  77,3500 183,9037    164,1492    155,7915    106,4854    50,6454 133,9083    5,1522  45,9496 173,7338    66,2271 59,4585 97,7969 60,2570 31,5231 149,8736    49,2935 158,383 128,7645    107,7448    103,7409    54,2279 196,5663
>   113   80,917  33,652  26,5553 72,8782 101,5024    108,4342    132,5383    116,8036    184,4999    88,7322 105,3388    187,6332    190,697 136,1984    96,712  91,4626 103,5248
>   114   29,9478 180,8490    189,3102    111,2027    192,6813    141,6388    72,8350 115,3112    152,9627    53,7352 129,168 107,2032    1,508   47,9480 35,490  17,8915 22,9960 27,714  31,7617 76,9690 117,7876    193,4000    103,1318    194,949 
>   115   152,4383    176,8236    75,9140 25,9233 9,7827  98,5825 52,4973 146,9828    81,2608 128,9072    86,4291 76,7291 90,1117 106,9598    144,3825    80,1417 114,3112    62,1913 39,983  91,1105 88,6611 129,7465    166,3001    61,3324 117,1399    94,3350 
>   116   78,2732 26,4221 113,8036    179,8099    32,6065 105,7899    62,7419 107,9864    82,8491 186,8639    176,4512    192,5906    57,656  4,6771  28,2638 10,1493 
>   117   98,9545 198,3936    42,7074 79,9043 102,2689    56,1934 114,7876    83,8516 86,4220 196,3366    1,2597  49,2896 138,7762    17,6266 115,1399
>   118   14,373  23,5079 4,3626  6,8547  123,2088    181,8129    18,6388 85,1102 31,6949 166,3979    35,8640 43,8008 45,5918 177,8279    110,9403    128,6289
>   119   80,108  154,741 130,730 84,6417 72,6215 30,7372 170,275 168,1890    157,9158    90,928  121,6261    37,9313 95,8126 14,960  87,518  79,4117 39,1376 163,5189    169,3511    195,617 3,7711  32,1914 19,7406 46,2687 196,2824    105,9930
>   120   40,7760 62,3851 72,2287 94,2733 86,5230 95,1104 164,5926    26,5788 18,44   155,6822    60,2231 185,556 45,5279 179,3327    159,5811    75,6892 64,2385 5,1862  178,8906    28,8874 51,5675 105,9333
>   121   4,7639  80,2257 197,6502    119,6261    136,1320    156,195 29,4537 7,8739  58,8818 32,1615 168,7186    62,4145 92,3819 173,2976    64,771  175,8821    191,8606    162,1977    132,3867    74,1468 165,7147    148,8115    55,44
>   122   78,6207 8,5338  174,8205    168,1574    162,3518    166,6712    135,6345    28,9165 192,1494    128,7247    189,2017    3,9640  148,3230    27,84   179,7377
>   123   14,2733 198,3493    6,13    104,9213    107,4581    89,1723 118,2088    128,1602    155,3251    46,132  36,6226 184,2832    103,8756    65,9599 124,6490    145,8804    193,7460
>   124   141,168 159,6580    42,3496 123,6490    77,8896 20,392  67,1880 158,1870    147,9014    165,9797    136,7388    56,552  11,6180 70,9089 45,3290 48,2593 
>   125   33,67   174,9048    95,2917 53,8054 1,2909  63,1315 76,1865 88,5012 58,1050 23,922  173,2615    188,230 172,8515    196,4519    138,9932    183,9920    7,5670
>   126   14,9602 4,2625  159,2980    86,937  181,8920    104,8615    179,7436    191,3989    161,4512    108,525 155,307 110,1073    134,5002    38,5441 76,9595 180,7176
>   127   4,6808  160,7534    26,9896 39,6103 50,3622 137,4069    60,1402 156,6372    2,9365  16,9807 56,3031 139,2526    14,5682 99,1408 167,3756    135,1752    161,6643    146,8151
>   128   14,9662 115,9072    123,1602    92,556  50,2987 190,2968    118,6289    157,6815    132,2789    184,6339    198,1860    112,7645    122,7247    85,4644 82,6834 100,2584    196,1760    12,7542 
>   129   6,8525  114,168 101,8821    77,2337 79,7314 47,9533 85,517  175,7121    184,5623    109,2464    143,8021    167,5370    25,3005 159,6895    115,7465
>   130   119,730 8,55    26,5706 45,4994 36,7589 30,1356 184,8488    178,615 92,4320 58,7020 82,3349 174,4481    66,5826 39,2414 194,9429    156,2264    20,9048 64,2493 43,2685 137,5926    190,3429    147,9251    111,9137    48,7921 38,5227 
>   131   14,358  98,4614 159,4355    75,5902 22,6075 43,8231 163,8625    11,833  57,6342 61,6924 82,3457 64,4631 134,6293    167,6269    2,7005  63,5257 9,700   103,2920    21,3748 
>   132   198,2393    113,5383    99,6234 138,5667    28,5604 19,3157 38,6092 85,3873 82,4162 25,219  182,6433    22,1560 147,2847    6,1514  121,3867    128,2789    51,6107 37,821
>   133   80,7217 112,9083    136,3739    77,2481 39,8145 43,8488 18,2702 27,7749 168,899 99,2090 190,9958    139,4719    182,8241    191,4296    85,836  153,8437    67,3802 49,5167 111,6767
>   134   197,6225    198,4071    92,610  79,5792 175,4489    36,979  131,6293    71,7485 146,9556    158,119 11,294  65,9956 135,276 16,5203 84,9312 126,5002    38,4730 
>   135   23,4560 4,7582  20,6434 174,6977    150,9732    190,1431    173,5664    144,6396    127,1752    122,6345    48,8869 82,519  158,8348    184,7629    78,6919 10,4650 134,276 194,5726    13,861
>   136   161,3866    195,4279    32,3823 84,4270 168,9519    54,1794 170,1529    197,9068    121,1320    194,2496    109,8658    199,7783    133,3739    145,1769    179,6711    26,7200 40,4658 174,5711    85,6221 113,1984    25,9251 184,6682    81,1409 88,9026 178,2752    124,7388
>   137   188,9117    100,7178    42,4572 51,1096 52,9846 97,4667 25,5378 102,6814    130,5926    84,4367 141,7872    23,7591 127,4069    157,5286    78,1910 91,4129 155,5736    67,1414 10,5273 110,8848
>   138   200,678 160,9902    26,7027 101,2902    51,8755 132,5667    43,7965 92,8080 1,7896  173,8555    33,6960 71,1229 46,2860 27,5918 188,892 169,7498    178,6589    125,9932    76,5683 117,7762    54,6261 140,5446
>   139   197,1386    98,1235 92,6763 181,5456    176,8186    182,2354    133,4719    158,3451    196,3988    73,4428 90,7846 155,2100    194,6966    69,9030 94,7116 127,2526    162,4510    9,8701  37,8208 
>   140   1,546   17,6440 97,6527 158,4029    151,5289    68,9624 138,5446    43,4482 169,2230    9,4163  155,5001    188,6223    102,6370    166,9829    65,5376 
>   141   154,3188    68,3540 106,674 79,7918 104,8162    24,6862 63,5607 6,8200  75,9237 150,2634    124,168 14,4477 112,130 164,6499    198,2621    114,6388    185,6820    59,9126 64,158  137,7872    81,4032 76,1969 48,7941 
>   142   66,777  17,8016 104,6236    18,332  47,5297 81,424  91,9164 150,2598    5,1195  34,7791 155,6613    169,7506    86,1663 100,2994    190,8070    2,7731  71,6038 145,5378    37,6433 
>   143   23,7543 6,3110  22,8603 108,972 25,108  81,9810 43,1171 186,8430    14,5848 129,8021    101,4042    76,1079 98,4300 155,2442    177,3884    36,5111 153,9940    96,9274 15,1041 176,5062
>   144   115,3825    173,8693    29,6452 98,7198 68,2277 195,652 102,7884    30,1616 111,5456    33,4841 13,9987 44,2276 86,8808 148,3617    35,3087 40,7772 101,3619    22,9362 184,5222    135,6396    90,6223 3,285   100,6605
>   145   200,2753    1,648   136,1769    26,6697 64,2685 174,7252    47,9483 108,521 44,2888 123,8804    71,6127 142,5378    20,8099 78,7244 110,6099    100,5512    55,3342 
>   146   115,9828    22,3620 47,2959 60,2317 5,5308  127,8151    7,4823  134,9556    18,9000 31,2837 17,5362 68,3895 72,4264 188,5715    167,52  107,7862    38,4400 
>   147   26,5759 59,2651 163,7221    95,1278 132,2847    124,9014    5,1087  34,9758 96,6736 38,8391 41,1858 167,5546    130,9251    149,6379    58,2267 93,7807 
>   148   160,3995    144,3617    185,2814    64,6419 18,589  30,4760 173,6725    179,6374    70,7231 155,6603    122,3230    192,4834    36,9550 121,8115    29,3252 
>   149   14,4352 59,2405 188,1003    163,9897    70,2366 83,6823 187,9580    174,2824    73,5233 112,8736    55,3088 18,2664 176,2255    190,3755    180,3407    147,6379
>   150   141,2634    1,2183  16,1680 41,7278 36,116  135,9732    11,4802 98,2093 58,4857 142,2598    73,8061 9,4539  18,5150 24,5669 52,634  190,5243    88,6770 53,662  7,9031  93,9213 
>   151   80,6728 156,6169    24,784  27,5915 174,1846    168,9216    99,4990 88,2295 178,5979    96,5643 83,162  13,9629 140,5289    189,9732    163,3624
>   152   161,6939    58,5877 48,5835 9,1087  8,1257  46,9550 189,8140    199,2697    109,2743    65,3595 186,2075    115,4383    50,5767 193,5444    90,4427 80,9606 114,9627    62,7404 79,6519 27,2124 111,1940    19,9751 93,6543 
>   153   17,8545 99,4560 70,6532 164,8748    29,5446 25,2477 72,541  143,9940    173,7613    77,4483 50,4905 165,897 133,8437    33,6574 67,6204 100,9522
>   154   141,3188    119,741 198,5078    156,8062    62,3238 20,2398 18,453  49,2962 187,1808    168,6317    200,229 185,1448    93,4073 78,8423 84,5421 41,901  60,6667 170,5971    19,4320 21,1845 199,5786
>   155   57,893  14,4446 98,5515 112,7915    123,3251    120,6822    25,3242 139,2100    143,2442    65,5533 142,6613    96,1251 137,5736    148,6603    61,5301 126,307 37,609  140,5001    194,6768
>   156   66,2965 42,6539 82,4691 53,4662 151,6169    7,7027  85,6669 29,5083 154,8062    130,2264    108,7039    34,8641 121,195 175,2205    69,9959 70,4830 127,6372    37,7714 
>   157   119,9158    26,7    86,4447 101,1393    187,7184    137,5286    99,6818 11,8497 2,8643  158,1881    128,6815    175,1597    72,604  24,9540 28,6880 15,2136 
>   158   78,6367 187,6714    91,5553 139,3451    169,1709    135,8348    63,5709 195,4912    140,4029    157,1881    124,1870    181,969 112,383 87,4081 134,119 
>   159   4,6133  160,4243    61,49   180,5757    6,9500  194,9391    43,9621 100,6567    126,2980    73,4969 131,4355    124,6580    1,7420  52,7816 74,8960 198,8330    42,5951 120,5811    87,19   36,6043 84,8763 129,6895    2,1397  51,3017 193,3786
>   160   14,7860 138,9902    127,7534    49,8648 85,3613 189,1530    57,2058 159,4243    183,9293    148,3995    87,8712 180,624 179,2542    91,383  42,2382 1,6461  77,105  28,9059 111,9702    19,3997 
>   161   152,6939    14,4275 23,6863 78,6310 136,3866    42,4792 62,4144 79,8395 127,6643    69,6171 126,4512    56,9811 196,9729    102,8230    88,1726 28,9217 
>   162   4,3924  98,6139 6,6897  59,391  194,1483    122,3518    57,6483 121,1977    179,9718    139,4510    199,7749    40,3056 111,8771    96,3737 45,3436 186,6114    48,201
>   163   1,8164  101,6033    41,5256 173,5799    15,818  13,3870 149,9897    131,8625    181,5593    119,5189    61,448  42,1278 68,4920 100,9709    147,7221    44,18   49,4688 192,2762    151,3624    89,4055 
>   164   141,6499    112,1492    42,347  120,5926    43,6849 87,3629 184,9774    170,328 153,8748    10,3866 172,9550    74,8627 195,9730    105,4661    24,7312 183,615 176,8681
>   165   23,208  6,6473  79,3768 187,1291    50,2667 153,897 166,4221    74,2602 21,2151 121,7147    124,9797    83,1555 65,3705 7,6019  41,3741 110,4097
>   166   23,8077 98,2364 79,8726 173,6917    44,6953 167,7080    118,3979    165,4221    168,4399    17,4762 9,8702  122,6712    20,6086 169,5530    115,3001    35,2816 55,3686 140,9829
>   167   23,2133 188,6549    187,9538    43,8120 18,7625 127,3756    180,6183    87,1022 79,820  83,8200 3,3877  129,5370    85,8110 193,8116    166,7080    131,6269    146,52  147,5546    45,1163 199,2001    93,5670 
>   168   119,1890    8,2076  136,9519    87,9716 154,6317    121,7186    133,899 122,1574    85,6193 173,3859    59,4170 27,1578 69,2357 151,9216    22,4356 70,1295 34,3923 166,4399    10,9495 52,1134 
>   169   14,4333 175,9164    177,2274    45,662  20,5990 63,5160 119,3511    104,3712    187,9225    192,8603    109,382 158,1709    55,7795 1,8700  138,7498    142,7506    166,5530    107,668 15,7485 54,2296 140,2230
>   170   119,275 1,2620  198,8089    136,1529    33,3648 18,4989 177,2774    44,6940 84,2436 2,9342  154,5971    164,328 45,8060 71,1539 94,9318 
>   171   188,6981    101,4083    16,3482 67,1394 61,6888 49,9736 182,4704    94,9959 10,2029 33,3913 185,5113    71,6702 6,3722  18,4403 72,8573 
>   172   200,6888    42,5383 72,3153 104,561 174,3433    102,6572    175,5353    35,992  73,2239 164,9550    29,5830 80,7715 77,4771 2,1438  60,2781 125,8515    13,2070 
>   173   112,7338    1,2069  144,8693    33,5949 17,7312 20,2676 18,7256 121,2976    168,3859    32,9631 148,6725    82,591  163,5799    192,2550    166,6917    179,4234    138,8555    44,5518 95,4092 153,7613    135,5664    61,4803 125,2615    193,4808    46,2969 
>   174   130,4481    89,858  73,2581 135,6977    68,7082 136,5711    91,3418 125,9048    122,8205    145,7252    72,2019 151,1846    172,3433    108,5669    99,5675 179,1886    149,2824    90,6914 
>   175   156,2205    187,2864    27,210  199,3779    67,5048 121,8821    169,9164    134,4489    65,7920 26,6165 172,5353    197,5909    8,1022  129,7121    14,6718 184,9107    70,3256 58,3675 157,1597
>   176   200,1709    115,8236    6,3512  33,3258 187,1128    191,3352    139,8186    149,2255    116,4512    46,9923 143,5062    51,1625 164,8681    107,6806    74,8129 
>   177   86,7010 92,3182 24,393  64,7660 102,4462    43,9544 22,8713 190,1332    14,6741 8,8508  170,2774    82,7882 169,2274    32,6902 53,9852 60,5345 143,3884    178,7547    118,8279    3,7097
>   178   130,615 72,5128 70,3394 13,4194 120,8906    11,1696 151,5979    16,1714 138,6589    102,1334    17,7464 49,9747 177,7547    35,5774 136,2752    28,3642 76,8433 
>   179   80,7729 160,2542    136,6711    120,3327    56,5284 50,2502 186,9993    180,664 104,8827    90,3149 74,1223 148,6374    174,1886    126,7436    173,4234    162,9718    116,8099    34,8528 52,3504 122,7377
>   180   160,624 159,5757    114,8490    59,2435 86,4604 39,9506 85,5525 179,664 191,6312    31,3598 149,3407    167,6183    89,6612 9,5995  126,7176    105,341 
>   181   112,2524    187,7956    41,5235 118,8129    185,9712    139,5456    76,3275 40,2338 11,8448 34,5267 102,3585    126,8920    106,5332    93,4071 91,5060 191,4844    163,5593    158,969 51,158
>   182   27,6234 47,8382 99,2897 139,2354    5,8806  133,8241    132,6433    56,7267 74,1873 35,7369 64,4701 107,8313    54,438  171,4704    2,7908  21,2447 
>   183   160,9293    112,9037    102,9634    99,3577 81,3061 88,5547 11,594  96,5939 53,5304 105,7722    26,4842 57,9093 70,5332 125,9920    164,615 38,5213 
>   184   6,8021  130,8488    188,198 40,4306 123,2832    101,9591    113,4999    129,5623    144,5222    175,9107    136,6682    164,9774    86,801  57,7592 29,9797 81,4485 35,7437 135,7629    28,4164 10,3207 128,6339
>   185   57,9772 105,1033    90,7284 52,8925 83,9306 97,7065 148,2814    25,3573 197,3140    50,3968 11,2045 141,6820    76,3674 108,8699    60,6670 188,700 120,556 181,9712    154,1448    30,3846 16,6280 109,6644    171,5113    19,5896 196,1339
>   186   57,8815 152,2075    197,1324    42,9391 188,5027    92,7980 179,9993    191,8255    58,8993 143,8430    116,8639    162,6114    71,7143 189,8128    195,2099    68,2528 103,9654
>   187   14,4874 200,6767    176,1128    37,4105 7,9522  175,2864    19,107  107,2610    167,9538    157,7184    24,9327 181,7956    42,3075 158,6714    165,1291    50,2485 154,1808    113,6332    169,9225    149,9580    10,4786 
>   188   23,4236 198,9114    137,9117    184,198 101,8531    167,6549    54,4883 149,1003    28,3816 196,88  52,7805 55,5181 185,700 186,5027    171,6981    97,4695 138,892 125,230 146,5715    140,6223
>   189   152,8140    160,1530    8,2780  114,3102    86,1115 40,4263 77,5702 50,7031 47,5939 85,1147 60,4415 69,5215 186,8128    198,9430    122,2017    51,8899 151,9732    193,2375
>   190   4,7536  200,5999    47,5892 113,697 130,3429    135,1431    150,5243    61,9775 69,8022 133,9958    128,2968    100,6674    17,7000 106,3305    9,3613  177,1332    31,5055 149,3755    142,8070    15,6854 105,2518
>   191   77,5135 126,3989    176,3352    94,8318 186,8255    121,8606    87,6921 44,8130 103,9683    75,1403 181,4844    50,5026 180,6312    111,5723    37,3573 133,4296
>   192   114,6813    97,6411 77,561  39,7454 22,4606 104,4219    27,5344 85,544  173,2550    91,6625 169,8603    116,5906    49,3113 163,2762    122,1494    148,4834
>   193   152,5444    167,8116    114,4000    55,8583 58,6166 189,2375    159,3786    96,8831 79,7737 21,494  28,9441 62,6610 123,7460    99,4566 173,4808    46,199
>   194   200,2915    159,9391    136,2496    130,9429    42,6498 92,426  139,6966    162,1483    73,8521 99,5832 155,6768    114,949 46,2429 79,5784 135,5726
>   195   23,3179 4,2490  197,5337    144,652 136,4279    6,2233  158,4912    186,2099    200,8114    61,8928 46,8206 164,9730    119,617 19,5038 67,5737 
>   196   188,88  39,9267 139,3988    95,231  61,5577 161,9729    125,4519    117,3366    103,696 46,9632 26,6754 112,5663    128,1760    119,2824    185,1339
>   197   54,2223 186,1324    121,6502    134,6225    68,8223 24,9337 25,3875 139,1386    81,5540 44,4900 195,5337    37,9188 111,4083    86,9714 110,751 136,9068    185,3140    104,4174    175,5909
>   198   141,2621    170,8089    44,2619 188,9114    41,7215 1,1724  154,5078    84,5999 16,2223 117,3936    123,3493    159,8330    69,6284 132,2393    134,4071    77,5081 50,3798 65,3575 36,6280 28,366  128,1860    189,9430
>   199   152,2697    8,1918  136,7783    59,8958 24,2838 175,3779    31,5564 162,7749    65,11   76,6878 9,70    89,2446 34,8196 167,2001    154,5786
>   200   108,9976    103,6851    145,2753    41,2622 187,6767    190,5999    16,2848 194,2915    5,4009  172,6888    39,4319 176,1709    60,3269 138,678 43,8943 98,2690 1,8021  104,7083    154,229 91,1988 67,475  76,4623 195,8114    37,7541 54,4899

Comment: Do you have opportunity show example file?

Comment: oh i forgot to post the answer. Actually the library is bugged, this is the answer, i ended up using another library and it worked fine...

Comment: Great, thanks. I think your code can still be improved. It is a Code Review yet, not SO. You can show `Algo I - PA5 - dijkstraData.txt`?

Comment: i've posted the new code in the answer

Comment: I saw. It's not just the website, in order to correct mistakes. "Code Review is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites". Perhaps you confused this site with SO?

Comment: feel free to comment the code that i posted.

Comment: https://github.com/FaguiCurtain/Learning-Fsharp/blob/master/Algos/Algos/Stanford%20Algo%20I/Algo%20I%20-%20PA5%20-%20dijkstraData.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42394/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-fagui-curtain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few small comments on the code:

1.
In function `parseLine`, when you parse file, you use `Array.filter (fun s -> not(s=""))` . But there is standard function for check it - [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Array.filter (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not)
```

2. 
In F# there is [Forward composition operator](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/09/fsharp-pipe-forward-and-pipe-backward/). You can apply it, for example, in function `nodelist`, to group conditions:

```
let nodelist = Array.map (fst >> int) y
```

3.
Not necessary use `new` when creating `SortedDeque`:

```
let PQ = SortedDeque<int*int>()
```

May be useful: [F# new keyword. What is it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829665/should-i-use-new-type-or-just-type-for-calling-a-constructor)

4.
Use short form to get elements of tuple.

> The tuple types in F# are somewhat more primitive than the other
>   extended types. As you have seen, you don’t need to explicitly define
>   them, and they have no name.
>
> It is easy to make a tuple -- just use a comma!
>
> And as we have seen, to "deconstruct" a tuple, use the same syntax:

[Taken from Tuples](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/tuples/)

So, instead:

```
let z = PQ.RemoveFirst()
let W = snd z
let l = fst z
```

better:

```
let l, W = PQ.RemoveFirst()
```

5.
Redundancy `init_loop`. Creating internal functions for only one invocation degrades the code readability.

6.
In my opinion such entry: `for k in 1..N do one_loop()` only confuses. There is nothing wrong if the body of the loop contain meaning!

7.
It is better to "invert" the conditions, if it saves you from writing "empty" branches. Instead:

```
    update_list 
      |> List.iter
           ( fun (node,dist) -> 
                if (inX.[node]=true) 
                   then ()
                   else let x = l+dist         
                        if x > D.[node] then ()
                                        else
```

better:

```
    for node, dist in graph.[W] do
        if inX.[node] |> not then 
            let x = l + dist     
            if x <= D.[node] then
```

8. Your function that implements the algorithm, contains the console output. It is better to avoid those moments. For example, if you want to add a GUI or web interface.
9. A lot of unnecessary brackets.

If you change it, you get:

Module Dijkstra:

```
module Dijkstra

open Spreads.Collections

let limit = 1000000 // max distance limit

let tryIndexOf (heap:SortedDeque<_>) elem = 
    try heap.IndexOfElement elem |> Some with 
    | :? System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException -> None

let dijkstraWithPath (graph: (int*int) list []) (s:int) (n:int) = // S = source
    let count = n + 1   

    let V = [s + 1..n] |> List.append [0..s - 1] // List.filter ((=) S >> not) [0..N]
    let A = Array.create count limit // on ne se sert pas de A.[0]
    let B = Array.create (n+1) [] 
    let C = Array.create count -1 // stores the index of the element in X nearest to an element in V.
    let D = Array.create count limit // stores the value of Dijkstra criterion
    let inX = Array.create count false // remembers if the node is in X (= has been processed)

    A.[s] <- 0
    inX.[s] <- true

    let PQ = SortedDeque<int*int>() // Key = distance to X ; Value = Node 

    for node in V do
        PQ.Add (limit, node)   

    for node, dist_to_S in graph.[s] do
        (limit, node)
        |> PQ.IndexOfElement 
        |> PQ.RemoveAt |> ignore

        (dist_to_S, node) 
        |> PQ.Add |> ignore

        B.[node] <- [s, node]
        C.[node] <- s
        D.[node] <- dist_to_S


    for k in 1..n do 
        let l, W = PQ.RemoveFirst()  // take the first element from the queue
        A.[W] <- l
        // maintain the heap
        // the Key must the Dijkstra criterion
        for node, dist in graph.[W] do
            if inX.[node] |> not then 
                let x = l + dist     
                if x <= D.[node] then 
                    match tryIndexOf PQ (D.[node], node) with 
                    | Some i ->  PQ.RemoveAt i |> ignore // updater le node                
                                 PQ.Add (x,node)
                                 C.[node]<- W // prédécesseur
                                 D.[node]<- x // update la distance à X      
                                 B.[node]<- (W, node)::B.[W]   
                    | None -> failwith "some information message"


        inX.[W] <- true

    // returns the array of all shortest paths with source A.[0]=limit doesn't mean anything.
    A, B |> Array.map List.rev
```

Test:

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Diagnostics

let stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

let path = "F:\Test.txt"

let x = File.ReadAllLines path

// original format of each row is "row_number (a1,b1) (a2,b2) ....(an,bn)"

let split (text:string) =
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let split_comma (text:string)=
    text.Split [|','|]

let splitIntoKeyValue (A: 'T[]) =  
    A.[0], A |> Array.toList |> List.tail

let parseLine line =
    line
    |> split
    |> Array.filter (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace >> not)
    |> splitIntoKeyValue

let y = Array.map parseLine x

let nodelist = Array.map (fst >> int) y

let N1 = Array.max nodelist // be careful if there is an image node with a bigger ID !!!

let graphcore = // nodes without outgoing edges will be missing
    y 
    |> Array.map (snd >> List.map split_comma)
    |> Array.map (List.map (fun (A:string[]) -> int A.[0], int A.[1]))

let N = 
    graphcore 
    |> Array.map (List.map fst >> List.max)
    |> Array.max // node max

// non-optimized construction
let graph = 
    let g = Array.create (N+1) []
    let count = Array.length nodelist
    for i in 0..count - 1 do
        g.[nodelist.[i]] <- graphcore.[i]
    g

let s = 1
let n = 200
let A, B  = Dijkstra.dijkstraWithPath graph s n

//stopWatch.Stop()
printfn "A = %A" A
printfn "B = %A" B
printfn "%f" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
Console.ReadKey(true) |> ignore
```

The name of the variable it is better to give meaningful, but not A,B,C,...x,y. I'm not familiar with graph theory, so couldn't fix it.

Comment: thank you for your time. 
the reason i used oneloop() is because i found it useful when using F# interactive for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

the code for PriorityQueue is bugged.
in some extreme case covered by the example above, it f*cks up

I ended up using another library,

open `Spreads.Collections`

and the following object
let PQ = new `SortedDeque`()

the full code can be found here
 https://github.com/FaguiCurtain/Learning-Fsharp/blob/master/Algos/Algos/Djikstra1d.fs

```ml
/////// solving Djikstra's shortest path algorithm in a directed graph ///////
/////// final version ///////

///////////////// preparing the data ////////////////////

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO

open Spreads
open Spreads.Collections

let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

// let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algos\Algos\Stanford Algo I\Algo I - PA5 - test4.txt"
let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algos\Algos\Stanford Algo I\Algo I - PA5 - dijkstraData.txt"

// val x : string [] =

// original format of each row is "row_number (a1,b1) (a2,b2) ....(an,bn)"

let split (text:string)=
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let split_comma (text:string)=
    text.Split [|','|]


let splitIntoKeyValue (A: 'T[]) =  
    (A.[0], Seq.toList (Seq.tail A))

let parseLine (line:string)=
    line
    |> split
    |> Array.filter (fun s -> not(s=""))
  //  |> Array.map (fun s-> (int s))
    |> splitIntoKeyValue

let y =
  x |> Array.map parseLine

let nodelist = y |> Array.map fst |> Array.map int

let N1 = Array.max nodelist // be careful if there is an image node with a bigger ID !!!


let graphcore = // (int*int) list [] // nodes without outgoing edges will be missing
    (y |> Array.map snd
       |> Array.map (List.map split_comma)
       |> Array.map (List.map (fun (A:string[]) -> (int A.[0],int A.[1]) )))


let N2 = graphcore |> Array.map (List.map fst) |> Array.map List.max |> Array.max // node max

let N=N2

// non-optimized construction

let graph = 
    let g = Array.create (N+1) []
    for i in 0..((Array.length nodelist)-1) do
        g.[nodelist.[i]] <- graphcore.[i]
    g

let graph1 = [| []; [(2,0)];[(3,0)];[(1,1);(4,0);(5,0)];[];[];[(5,2);(4,2)]|]      
let linear_graph2 = [| []; [(2,1)] ; [(3,1)];[(4,1)];[] |]
let graph3 =[| []; [(2,1);(3,1)] ; [(4,1)];[(4,1)];[] |]

/////////////////// DJIKSTRA ///////////////////
let limit = 1000000 // max distance limit

// computes all shortest path distances from the source S and returns it in an array
let Djikstra (graph: (int*int) list []) (S:int) (N:int)= // S = source

    let V = [0..N] |> List.filter (fun s -> not(s=S))
    let A = Array.create (N+1) limit // on ne se sert pas de A.[0]
    A.[S] <- 0

    let C = Array.create (N+1) -1 // stores the index of the element in X nearest to an element in V.
    let D = Array.create (N+1) limit // stores the value of Dijkstra criterion

    let inX = Array.create (N+1) false // remembers if the node is in X (= has been processed)
    inX.[S]<-true

    let PQ = new SortedDeque<int*int>() // Key = distance to X ; Value = Node 
    let GetIndexOf (heap:SortedDeque<int*int>) elem = 
        try Some (heap.IndexOfElement elem) with | :? System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException -> None

    let init_loop () : unit =
        for node in V do
            PQ.Add (limit,node)
        for (node,dist_to_S) in graph.[S] do
             PQ.RemoveAt (PQ.IndexOfElement (limit,node)) |> ignore
             PQ.Add (dist_to_S,node) |> ignore
             C.[node]<-S
             D.[node]<-dist_to_S
    init_loop()

    let one_loop() =
        // take the first element from the queue
        let z = PQ.RemoveFirst()
        let W = snd z
        let l = fst z
        A.[W]<- l
        // maintain the heap
        // the Key must the Dijkstra criterion
        let update_list = graph.[W]
        update_list 
          |> List.iter
               ( fun (node,dist) -> 
                    if (inX.[node]=true) 
                       then ()
                       else let x = l+dist                                                    
                            if x > D.[node] then ()
                                            else 
                                                match GetIndexOf PQ (D.[node],node) with 
                                                  | None -> printfn "error at node %d with temp=%d" node D.[node]
                                                            printfn "update_list = %A" update_list
                                                            failwith "stopping program"
                                                  | Some i ->  PQ.RemoveAt i |> ignore // updater le node                
                                                               PQ.Add (x,node)
                                                               C.[node]<- W // prédécesseur
                                                               D.[node]<- x // update la distance à X                                  
                              ) 
        inX.[W] <- true


    for k in 1..N do one_loop()

    A // returns the array of all shortest paths with source A.[0]=limit doesn't mean anything.
///// end of Djikstra ////

///// same as above but also returns a path with minimum distance (there may be more than one) 
let Djikstra_with_path (graph: (int*int) list []) (S:int) (N:int)= // S = source
    let V = [0..N] |> List.filter (fun s -> not(s=S))
    let A = Array.create (N+1) limit // on ne se sert pas de A.[0]
    A.[S] <- 0

    //
    let B = Array.create (N+1) [] 
    //
    let C = Array.create (N+1) -1 // stores the index of the element in X nearest to an element in V.
    let D = Array.create (N+1) limit // stores the value of Dijkstra criterion

    let inX = Array.create (N+1) false // remembers if the node is in X (= has been processed)
    inX.[S]<-true

    let PQ = new SortedDeque<int*int>() // Key = distance to X ; Value = Node 
    let GetIndexOf (heap:SortedDeque<int*int>) elem = 
        try Some (heap.IndexOfElement elem) with | :? System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException -> None

    let init_loop () : unit =
        for node in V do
            PQ.Add (limit,node)      
        for (node,dist_to_S) in graph.[S] do
             PQ.RemoveAt (PQ.IndexOfElement (limit,node)) |> ignore
             PQ.Add (dist_to_S,node) |> ignore
             C.[node]<-S
             D.[node]<-dist_to_S
             B.[node]<-[(S,node)]
    init_loop()
    // printfn "init ok"
    let one_loop() =
        // take the first element from the queue
        let z = PQ.RemoveFirst()
        let W = snd z
        let l = fst z
        A.[W]<- l
        // maintain the heap
        // the Key must the Dijkstra criterion
        let update_list = graph.[W]
        update_list 
          |> List.iter
               ( fun (node,dist) -> 
                    if (inX.[node]=true) 
                       then ()
                       else let x = l+dist                                                    
                            if x > D.[node] then ()
                                            else 
                                                match GetIndexOf PQ (D.[node],node) with 
                                                  | None -> printfn "error at node %d with temp=%d" node D.[node]
                                                            printfn "update_list = %A" update_list
                                                            failwith "stopping program"
                                                  | Some i ->  PQ.RemoveAt i |> ignore // updater le node                
                                                               PQ.Add (x,node)
                                                               C.[node]<- W // prédécesseur
                                                               D.[node]<- x // update la distance à X      
                                                               B.[node]<- (W,node)::B.[W]                          
                              ) 
        inX.[W] <- true


    for k in 1..N do one_loop()

    (A,(B|> Array.map List.rev)) // returns the array of all shortest paths with source A.[0]=limit doesn't mean anything.


// stopWatch.Stop()
let (A,B) = Djikstra_with_path graph 1 200
printfn "A = %A" A
printfn "B = %A" B
printfn "%f" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```